# Making bigger steel frame smaller

Tags: frames, bike-fit

i bought old Peugeot carbolite 103. With size 60cm which is very big for me, so I have an idea to cut it to 50cm. Do you think it's worth it and the risks?

---

Edit: Guys thanks for the fastest responding. I will search for another frame.

Comment: As someone who needs large frames - please don't take one out of circulation.  Instead, sell it and buy one that suits your size.

Comment: Old bikes with good, usable frames but worn out, missing and broken components are common. If the components on this bike are good, use it as a donor bike onto another, with a smaller frame.

Comment: I think this is one of those “If you have to ask, the answer is no” type situations.

Comment: If it's a French bike made before 2000s, there's a good chance some components have French threads and you need another similar frame to reuse the components.

Answer (score 22):

It isn’t possible to resize a bike like this. You would be talking about removing each individual tube, cutting it down to size, and then rejoining them. We would be talking about *all* the tubes, not just one. You don’t know how much to remove. You don’t know how to rejoin the tubes. You would basically be destroying the bike to rebuild it even if you knew these factors. It would have been better to buy the correct size bike to being with, and if you have no idea what is the correct size you are better off buying new from a store or getting a knowledgeable friend to help.

One other factor to consider is how economical this action would be. Even if it were practical to re-construct the frame, you'd need to remove all the parts. You aren't likely to have the tools to do this, so this is already a bit of a pricey proposition. Given that these are steel tubes, you'd also need the equipment to cut and miter the tubes so that they can be joined. Then you'd need equipment for joining the tubes - I think the frame isn't [lugged](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/37138/), but I can't tell if it's [brazed](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/37137/7044) or [welded](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/37139/7044). Whatever the case, the framebuilding equipment is much more expensive than tools for bike servicing. Even if the process were possible and you had the skills to do it, this is unlikely to be practical unless you're already a framebuilder.

While not directly relevant to the question, one commenter referenced the concept of the Ship of Theseus. This is a thought experiment used in the metaphysics of identity. As applied to bicycles, [the consensus](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/72371/what-are-the-most-basic-parts-of-a-bicycle-which-cannot-be-upgraded-over-a-perio) is that if you upgrade the frame, it is essentially a totally different bicycle. That would seem to apply here.

Comment: Agreed. This would be tantamount to building a frame from scratch, which is a major, expensive undertaking (watch some youtube videos on hobbyist framebuilding to see what you'd be signing up for). If you do it wrong, the results would be at best unsatisfactory, at worst dangerous.

Comment: Indeed, such work would be so extensive it approaches Ship of Theseus levels of debating whether it's even the "same" bike at that point.

Comment: Indeed. You’d basically have to cut down the frame into individual tubes, then shorten them appropriately (you could take the dimensions from a smaller frame) and re-build the whole frame. Even if you have suitable welding equipment you’d need a jig to hold the tubes in place.

Comment: Another point - if the frame tubes are butted, cutting them down could remove some or all of the thicker end of the tube, resulting in a tube and join of substandard strength.

Comment: I think building a frame from new tubes would be easier than cutting an existing frame and rebuilding it to smaller size.

Comment: *"you are better off buying new from a store or getting a knowledgeable friend to help"* - Heck, you would even be better off **building a new frame from raw materials** than you would be trying to rebuild a frame by salvaging the materials from a used one.